# How to view a stream containing html executed via link?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, razor

I have a WCF service that contains a function that will return a stream containing html given an ID.

I need to call it view a link such as http://webservice/123

There will be many links generated like the above on a page.

I am totally in the blank of how to implement it so that if I click the link the html within the stream will be shown as a page.

I am looking for ideas of how to implement this or any resources that help me achieve this.

Comment: You have to at least show us what this wcf output look like.

Comment: So your WCF service is returning HTML code and you are including that in your view, but it is showing up as encoded text instead of embedded as html? Is that correct? If so you will need to use `Html.Raw`, but be careful with that.

Comment: And I are with Kosala, it would be helpful if we could see an example of the output received from the WCF service. It would also be helpful to see some code of how you are using that data in your page.